# Why is the Xamarin linear progress bar cut in half when I set a corner radius on Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I am using the Syncfusion [Xamarin ProgressBar](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/progressbar/overview) with a corner radius (version 17.4.0.55):

```xml
<progressBar:SfLinearProgressBar
    HeightRequest="16"
    CornerRadius="16"
    Progress="75"
    ProgressColor="#FFffbe06"
    TrackColor="#33ffbe06"
    TrackHeight="16" />
```

On Android the corner radius applies to the middle of the bar in addition to the sides. It appears to cut the progress bar in two.

[image]

This problem does not exist on iOS.

[image]

I attempted to solve the issue by setting the SegmentCount to "1". But that did not solve the issue.

```xml
<progressBar:SfLinearProgressBar
    ...
    SegmentCount="1" />
```

What do I need to update in my XAML to avoid the middle corner radius?

Comment: Syncfusion has great support, it's better if you ask them directly through the issue tracker or their live chat.

Comment: I change the `HorizontalOptions` to `FillAndExpand` for better showing. Please check my screenshot: https://imgur.com/EctaJVo I need more details to reproduce.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I tried what you suggested but it did not work. What version are you using?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT The answer from Richard Valdivieso solved my issue. This bug only appears when you run the app in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review this using Syncfusion's example app, I discovered that there is a difference between running the app in Debug mode and Run mode. Here is an example of both modes:

[image: Debug Mode]

[image: Run Mode]

The top image is in debug mode and you can see the little gap on it. The bottom one is in Run mode and it is a perfect progress bar.

Definitely is something that needs to be reported to Syncfusion as a bug.